# how to combine dropdownlists and null fields in gridview?

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

i have a GridView with LinqDataSource.
im using the following technique to populate a field (Supplier in this case) with dropdownlist, containing values from a different LinqDataSource:

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/linq5/step27.jpg))</sub>

however, lets say my Supplier field is allowed to be null. any ideas how to allow entering null value, alongside with the other SupplierDataSource options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"
      DataSourceID="SupplierDataSource"
      DataValueField="SupplierID"
      DataTextField="CompanyName"
      SelectedValue='<%#Bind("SupplierID")%>'
      runat="server"
      AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="None" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This should add an empty list item to your dropdown. I believe your datasource will interpret this as a null value, but I have not tested the code yet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is pretty cool... good for adding a default option like "Unspecified" or whatever